# ASP.NET how to push text from texbox using ajax into another page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this code where I want to post text to search.aspx from default.aspx using ajax, is this possible?

**default.aspx**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="search-container">
        <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="look for Musics"/>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').bind('keyup', function() {
        var searchTerm = jQuery.trim($(this).val());

        if(searchTerm == '') {
            $('#search-container ul').html('');
        }
        else {
            //send the data to the database
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.aspx',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { search:searchTerm },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#search-container ul').html('<li>Loading...</li>');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#search-container ul').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**search.aspx**

```
string term = //this is the part i want to store text from default.aspx

string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|mydb.mdb";
DataTable results = new DataTable();

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT title FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%'"+term+"'% ' ",conn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(results);

    if (results.Rows.Count != 0) 
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                terms = reader[0].ToString();

                searchbox.InnerText = terms;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the code I have 
I am unable to get text from default.aspx page to search.aspx

Comment: Please send `search.aspx` file as well

Comment: try `string term = Request["search"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `string term = Request["search"]`